# Is it advisable to use $watch instead of binding to a function in a large angular app to enhance performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried:

```
<div ng-show="isDirty()" />

$scope.isDirty = function() {
    console.log('isDirty');
    return field.isDirty;
}
```

and

```
<div ng-show="isDirty" />

$scope.$watch('field.isDirty', function(oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log('isDirty');
    $scope.isDirty = newValue;
});
```

The first option fired many more times than the second. The first option also fired when I did things unrelated to field.isDirty.

Comment: totally depends on application design..if you put a `$watch` on the variable that changes oftenly and there are 100 variables like it..then it will mess with performance..Generally I'd prefer second way of doing ..but sometimes we need to old value while we've `newValue` at that time you need to go with watch & also watcher performs dirty checking that may cause performance issue. https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/

Comment: Remember that `ng-show` *adds a watch*. So, 1st version is 1 watch of a simple function call. OK. Second version is 2 watches; moreover the change happens in two stages: `field.isDirty` is watched, found to have changed and then `$scope.isDirty` is set. This triggers **ANOTHER DIGEST CYCLE** to update the DOM. So 2nd solution => 2 watches and 2 digest cycles => BAD.

Comment: I know this is just an example, but why not `ng-show="field.isDirty"`?

Answer (score 0):

The first option fired more times, because you actually fire it in different cases. In first case there is a watcher for your function result. It fires every digest circle to get a new value and to compare it with old one. In second options there is very close to the first watcher. But you just cannot see it fires every digest circle. You see only when result actually changed.

To make experiment honest you should use watcher without expression ([From AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)):

`If you want to be notified whenever $digest is called, you can register a watchExpression function with no listener. (Since watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest cycle when a change is detected, be prepared for multiple calls to your listener.)`

Comment: And yeah, as mentions @NikosParaskevopoulos, second variant adds second watcher for `$scope.isDirty` property.